# Are the stories in the Midrashim and Targumim meant to be historical?

Tags: tanach, midrash, rabbis, tannaim, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

The Midrashim and Targumim contain stories meant to further elaborate on the accounts in the Hebrew Bible. Are these stories meant to be historically accurate?

Further reading on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends which. Some just come to emphasize certain points in a story in Tanach using different words.

Comment: They’re meant to teach you something but are not always literal